# JS scope: accessing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I know this question has been asked many times, but in different forms. I want to access the `selected` variable elsewhere within the scope of the topmost function (`alert` is currently returning undefined). I know I need to use a `return` in some way or another. Thank you in advance.

```
$('#people_search_mobile').change(function() {

  var selected;

  $('li a', $('#suggestions')).bind('click.autocomplete',function(){ 
    selected = ($(this).text());
  });

  alert(selected);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meagar is correct, however I find that sometimes it helps to write the function elsewhere, that way I am keeping the event handler clean.

```
$('#people_search_mobile').change(function() {

  var selected, myClickHandler;

  myClickHandler = function(){
    selected = ($(this).text());
    alert(selected);
  };

  $('li a', $('#suggestions')).bind('click.autocomplete', myClickHandler);

}
```

**Edit:** Or if you want to pass the selected value to another function elsewhere...

```
  myClickHandler = function(){
    selected = ($(this).text());
    showMyAlert(selected);
  };

...

function showMyAlert(selected){
  alert(selected);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't make any sense.  The `li a` hasn't been clicked yet, when the `alert` happens. The `alert` will *always* show `undefined`, the code to assign a value to `selected` *has not run*, and *may never run*.

If you want to alert the value, you need to do so at the time the `li a` is actually clicked:

```
$('#people_search_mobile').change(function() {

  var selected;

  $('li a', $('#suggestions')).bind('click.autocomplete',function(){ 
    selected = ($(this).text());
    alert(selected);
  });


}
```

Comment: ok, but if i want to pass this value to another function outside of '.bind', what is the best way to do that?

Comment: @PaulOsetinsky Move that code inside the event handler, where I've placed the `alert`.